# A way to count amount of elements in-between another element and returning an array

Tags: python, web-scraping

So, I am trying to scrape data off a page to analyze it with R. In order for a complete analysis I need to be able to account for the day of each infection. The page portrays it's content as so:

```
<h4> 5 of March </h4>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    x10
</ul>
<h4> 4 of March </h4>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    x15
</ul>
<h4> 3 of March </h4>
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

and so on until the 21 of Januray.

What I want to do is to count the amount of `<li>` that are within a given `<ul>` that corresponds to its `<h4>` and for python to give me back a list that repeats the `<h4>` string the `<li>` amount of times.
So for example, in `<h4>` 5 of March `<h4>` case I would want a list that repeats "5 of March" 12 times, because there are 12 `<li>` that correspond to that `<h4>`.

so far this is my code, but it doesn't even return something to me:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(#purposefully left blank)

amount = []
cases = []
deaths = []
Country = [] 
Province = [] 

driver.get("https://bnonews.com/index.php/2020/01/timeline-coronavirus-epidemic/")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

h4_tag = str(soup.findAll('h4'))
li_tag = str(soup.findAll('li'))

FLAGS = re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE
```

At this point I was just trying to see if I could count the amount of `<ul>` elements but I can't even do that... 
Any Ideas? I've checked stack and git for answers but to no avail...

**UPDATE**
the code `findChildren` doesn't work because the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements are not children of the `<h4>` element. Removed "recursive"

```
ul_tag =  soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'mvp-post-soc-in'})
children = ul_tag.find('li')
print(children)
```

This code returns a list with all `<li>` elements and their content.

**Trying to check if soup(content) is string**
This is what I get when I print soup:

```
<html lang="en-US" style="transform: none;"><head><meta content="60109657413" property="fb:pages"/>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" id="viewport" name="viewport"/>
<link href="https://bnonews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/favicon2.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/><link href="https://bnonews.com/xmlrpc.php" rel="pingback"/>
<meta content="article" property="og:type"/>
<meta content="https://bnonews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/2019EbolaWorker.jpg" property="og:image"/>
<meta content="https://bnonews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/2019EbolaWorker.jpg" name="twitter:image"/>
<meta content="https://bnonews.com/index.php/2020/01/timeline-coronavirus-epidemic/" property="og:url"/>
<meta content="TIMELINE: Coronavirus epidemic" property="og:title"/>
<meta content="The following is a timeline of new cases in China and around the world. It is updated once a day. For the current day, click here. Timeline (GMT) 10 March 23:57: First 2 cases in Bolivia. (Source) 23:40: 21 new cases and 1 new death in Spain. (Source) 23:39: 1 new case in Nebraska, United […]" property="og:description"/>
<meta content="summary" name="twitter:card"/>
<meta content="https://bnonews.com/index.php/2020/01/timeline-coronavirus-epidemic/" name="twitter:url"/>
<meta content="TIMELINE: Coronavirus epidemic" name="twitter:title"/>
<meta content="The following is a timeline of new cases in China and around the world. It is updated once a day. For the current day, click here. Timeline (GMT) 10 March 23:57: First 2 cases in Bolivia. (Source) 23:40: 21 new cases and 1 new death in Spain. (Source) 23:39: 1 new case in Nebraska, United […]" name="twitter:description"/>
<title>TIMELINE: Coronavirus epidemic - BNO News</title>
<link href="https://bnonews.com/index.php/2020/01/timeline-coronavirus-epidemic/" rel="canonical"/>
<meta content="en_US" property="og:locale"/>
<meta content="article" property="og:type"/>
<meta content="TIMELINE: Coronavirus epidemic - BNO News" property="og:title"/>
<meta content="The following is a timeline of new cases in China and around the world. It is updated once a day. For the current day, click here. Timeline (GMT) 10 March 23:57: First 2 cases in Bolivia. (Source) 23:40: 21 new cases and 1 new death in Spain. (Source) 23:39: 1 new case in Nebraska, United …" property="og:description"/>
<meta content="https://bnonews.com/index.php/2020/01/timeline-coronavirus-epidemic/" property="og:url"/>
<meta content="BNO News" property="og:site_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ul` is not contained within the parent container you want to print, you will probably have to walk the html elements and print as you go, checking for the different elements along the way.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<h4> 5 of March </h4><ul><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul><h4> 4 of March </h4><ul><li></li><li></li></ul><h4> 3 of March </h4><ul><li></li></ul>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

current_h4 = ''
for e in soup:
    if e.name == 'h4':
        current_h4 = e.text
    if e.name == 'ul':
        for li in e.find_all('li'):
            print(current_h4)
```

Result:

```
 5 of March 
 5 of March 
 5 of March 
 5 of March 
 5 of March 
 5 of March 
 5 of March 
 5 of March 
 5 of March 
 5 of March 
 5 of March 
 5 of March 
 4 of March 
 4 of March 
 3 of March
```

**Additional Update**:
Here is a working example using your exact data source. It is easier to target the `div` that contains your data directly (id="mvp-content-main") instead of one of the parent divs. I believe the issues you were having was in navigating down the child elements to the one you actually wanted. The result below prints 2,596 lines.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'your/path/here/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://bnonews.com/index.php/2020/01/timeline-coronavirus-epidemic/")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
ul_tag = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'mvp-content-main'})

current_h4 = ''
for e in ul_tag:
    if e.name == 'h4':
        current_h4 = e.text
    if e.name == 'ul':
        for li in e.find_all('li'):
            print(current_h4)
```

Comment: In my particular case, when I do:

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser') where content is defined as the html paged (in the code up above) 

I don't get any return, not even "None" or "[]". Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the print of the content to make sure it is a string of html?

Comment: I added it to the question!. How would I go about making it into a string?

Comment: Try using the parser “html5lib” instead of html.parser if you are using content like you are.

Comment: I've installed and tried using "html5lib" but I cannot seem to get the correct output.

Comment: The html you have posted as a result doesn’t contain any h4 or li elements, so the loop I posted wouldn’t print anything.

Comment: I only copied a portion so as to see how the output would look. The <li> and <h4> elements were printed

Comment: Make sure you are only looping over the elements inside the div that you have called the `ul_tag`, not the entire page.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use the exact data source you want, instead of an example. I believe the reason you were getting no output is because you weren't inside of the correct `div`.